# Apache SolrCloud query stuck in Data Import Handler

Tags: indexing, solrcloud, dataimporthandler, dih

We are doing auto syncing of records using delta importers. But some collections start to stop indexing and they stuck the importer means no more indexing.

If we are unable to catch this long running stuck query, then other collections start adapting same behaviour (means they also stuck to process records).

Eventually, the solr collections goes to recovery and we get to know that we have long running stuck queries in data importer.

**Our configuration:** 5 servers of 8 cores 64 gb ram 1 tb space each.

What can be causing this issue?